# Why would a company be "required" to hold bonds in Europe?

Tags: investing, government-bonds, europe

I was just watching an old recording of one of Berkshire Hathaway's shareholder meetings and Charlie Munger made a statement about being "required" to hold bonds in Europe.  Why would they be required to hold bonds?  Is it some sort of regulatory thing?

https://youtu.be/iU61G1zO5yw?si=IsBe43iE-1bmo96V&t=556

Comment: Perhaps in the sense of "bonded and insured" rather than savings bonds?

Comment: I am not an expert, but I can't imagine that there is something like an obligation to hold european bonds (by law) in any case. Maybe he meant that Berkshire needs to invest in bonds for some business reason. E.g. to avoid or have some currency effects.